# The limit of $|z|^2/z$ in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

What is the limit of $|z|^2\over z$ in the complex plane at $z_0=0$?

This is how I do it: ${|z|^2\over z}={{x^2+y^2}\over {x+iy}} $, then along the real axis, and the imaginary axis, the limit approaches different value, namely $y/i$ and $x$, so the limit DNE. Is that correct?

Comment: The limit at $0$ cannot involve $x$ or $y$, as yours do.  In fact, both $y/i$ and $x$ go to $0$ at $0$, which is connected to the limit you want.

Comment: The limit of both those quantities *are* zero. You have not taken a limit.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up, and makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{|z|^2}z=\frac{z\overline z}z=\overline z\xrightarrow[z\to 0]{}0$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(z)=|z|^2/z$ then

$$\lim_{z\to0}|f(z)|=|z|=0$$
so

$$\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=0$$